# Cannot locate Read Only Domain Controller from certain sockets using C# auth

Tags: c#, active-directory, iis-7.5

We use C# and System.DirectoryServices to do authentication against ActiveDirectory. This is through IIS 7.5+ using custom attributes and handling of user credentials. Some sites will completely fail to locate the read only domain controller or fail at authenticating users. Usually this results in an exception in the EventViewer.

If we modify the code to directly target a specific domain controller, the problem goes away. However, ever site/service we have should be using the read only domain controller.
Doing retry logic fails.
Every time a request is authenticated it gets a new implementation of the ActiveDirectory services.
We've tried to fix memory leaks when calling to get DirectoryEntry and DirectorySearcher objects. This hasn't helped.

```
public string CreateUsernameFilter(string username)
        {
            return string.Format("(&(ObjectClass=user)(sAMAccountName={0}))", username);
        }

        public DirectoryEntry CreateDirectoryEntry(string username, string password)
        {
            return new DirectoryEntry(Domain, username, password, AuthenticationTypes.ReadonlyServer);
        }

        public DirectorySearcher CreateDirectorySearcher(DirectoryEntry entry, SearchScope scope = SearchScope.Subtree, ReferralChasingOption option = ReferralChasingOption.All)
        {
            return new DirectorySearcher(entry) { SearchScope = scope, ReferralChasing = option };
        }

        public SearchResult ProcessSearch(DirectorySearcher searcher, string filter)
        {
            searcher.Filter = filter;
            return searcher.FindOne();
        }
```

Additional info - calls:

```
            using (var entry = Handler.CreateDirectoryEntry(username, password))
            {
                using (var searcher = Handler.CreateDirectorySearcher(entry))
                {
                    var filter = Handler.CreateUsernameFilter(username);
                    var result = Handler.ProcessSearch(searcher, filter);
                    var isAuth = result != null;
                    ReportMessage(EventArgsMessageType.Info, "'{0}' is{1} authenticated.", username,
                        isAuth ? "" : " not");
                    return MapResult(result, username, isAuth);
```

We get errors when calling GetComputerSite:

```
Exception type: InvalidCastException 
Exception message: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Byte[]' to type 'System.String'.
```

at System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.ActiveDirectorySite.GetServers()
   at System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.ActiveDirectorySite.get_Servers()

EDIT 2:
I apologize, here's where the issue sometimes occurs:

```
var site = ActiveDirectorySite.GetComputerSite();
```

The other thing is sometimes that's not where it fails either, there are sometimes errors with the Searcher doing filters. However, when the above line fails, it fails constantly for a socket https://*someportal*.domain.com/ and https://*someportal-test*.domain.com/

EDIT 3: 
Additional Exception data:

```
Exception information: 
    Exception type: COMException 
    Exception message: This operation returned because the timeout period expired.

   at System.DirectoryServices.PropertyValueCollection.PopulateList()
   at System.DirectoryServices.PropertyValueCollection..ctor(DirectoryEntry entry, String propertyName)
   at System.DirectoryServices.PropertyCollection.get_Item(String propertyName)
   at System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.PropertyManager.GetPropertyValue(DirectoryContext context, DirectoryEntry directoryEntry, String propertyName)
```

Comment: Can you show the code you use to actually authenticate the users? And what is the actual exception that you are getting?

Comment: Also, any reason you are not using Windows Authentication?

Comment: We developed this as an SSO solution so we create a DirectoryEntry with the user credentials and then use a DirectorySearcher to locate additional properties for roles. Have to edit original question to add more info.

Comment: Which line is throwing the exception? Seems like an easy problem to fix.

Comment: I apologize, I forgot to post the code where we're locating the server:
var site = ActiveDirectorySite.GetComputerSite();

Comment: Maybe try getting the output of `Domain.GetCurrentDomain().DomainControllers` (all the DC's for the current domain) and try connecting to each one and see if you can identify one specific one that is causing problems. I have a feeling there is something wrong with the way your domain is configured.

Comment: @GabrielLuci I know which one it has issues with its the readonly controller. For some reason if we target a specific AD controller that's not the readonly one, it works 100% of the time. However, if we specifically target the readonly controller we'll get other errors.

Comment: I'm looking at the .NET Core source code for [ActiveDirectorySite.GetServers()](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/a10890f4ffe0fadf090c922578ba0e606ebdd16c/src/System.DirectoryServices/src/System/DirectoryServices/ActiveDirectory/ActiveDirectorySite.cs#L1387) (even if you're not using .NET Core, the source is probably the same in .NET Framework). The only place it casts to `string` is when it retrieves the `dnsHostName` attribute on the computer object of the DC. But I don't understand why that would ever be a `byte[]`. But you could check that attribute in Users and Computers.

Comment: @GabrielLuci exactly! This is what's been throwing us. I added an additional exception we receive on some other sites. Namely its a COM exception for getting property attributes.

Comment: That exception just means the server didn't reply.

Comment: @GabrielLuci but its a constant exception and based on socket too, which is the other odd thing. So specific URLs can never hit this authentication until the app pool is restarted. Its random too.

Comment: What do you mean by "based on socket"?

Comment: By socket I mean https://*somedomain*.mydomain.com/ fails but not https://*someotherdomain*.mydomain.com/ - they both call out to a service that handles the authentication at like https://sso.mydomain.com/

Comment: It really does sound like there is a domain controller that is either misconfigured or completely off, but is still being advertised as a DC. I don't think it's your code. Do you have AD Users and Computers on your machine? You can try using that to connect to the problem DC and see what happens.

Comment: Thank you @GabrielLuci I agree with you 100%, but can't seem to get IT to investigate too much further. The issue is so sporadic that it can take a few hours to a few days before it shows up again. I really appreciate all the correspondence.

Comment: Yes, that sounds like a bad DC. When you make a connection and don't specify a DC, it picks one for you. It sounds like it happens to pick the bad one sometimes because it is being advertised as a DC (probably in DNS) even though it is not working. You can check DNS by doing a DNS lookup on your domain name (`nslookup example.com`). If the IP of the bad DC is showing up, then that's your problem.